# 'LiveData' requires that 'User' inherit from 'LiveObject'

Tags: swift, realm

My project uses Swift 5.1 and I am experiencing difficulties running my unit tests with some Swift generics.

I have the code below with some type aliases and functions:

```swift
final class User: LiveObject { //... }
```

```swift
func loadAllUsers(_ database: Database) -> LiveData<User> {
  database.objects(User.self)
}
```

Database:

```swift
typealias Object = LiveObject
func objects<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> LiveData<T> where T: Object {
  realm.objects(type)
}
```

`LiveData` and `LiveObject` are type aliases or extension of `Realm`s types:

```swift
public typealias LiveData<T> = RealmSwift.Results<T> where T: LiveObject //[1. Requirement specified as 'T' : 'LiveObject' [with T = User]]
public typealias LiveList<T> = RealmSwift.List<T> where T: LiveObject

open class LiveObject: RealmSwift.Object { //... }
```

But when calling the code below:

```swift
let users: LiveData<User> = loadAllUsers(database)
```

I get this error: `'LiveData' requires that 'User' inherit from 'LiveObject'`.

I really don't know what is happening, the code compiles fine the main application, the problem only happens when I run the XCTest. All the functions above are also called in the main application. I don't understand why the compiler cannot detect that `User inherits` LiveObject` when running the XCTest.

Error log:

[image]

I believe it's a problem with overloaded functions and objc. Is that correct?

Edit 1: Removing the types from the function sorted most of the issues (but why?).

Thanks!

Comment: This `typealias Object = LiveObject` may be an issue because it seems backwards - I may be misunderstanding the purpose though. I belive the general structure is `aliasName = existingObjectName`. And that code is telling `Object` (which is an existing Realm Object) that it is an alias of `LiveObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in the past when the object referenced in the Xcode errors had target membership in both a framework and a service. In reality, the object only needed the target membership in the framework because the service imported the framework. Having the target membership in both when one was importing the other created a circular reference and caused the confusing errors in Xcode. The solution was to remove the unnecessary target membership.